# Why below method 1 cannot achieve the sorting function but method 2 does?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a sorting function for a list.
I don't know why the method 2 can do the sorting but method 1 doesn't.
I think in method 1 I advance the pointers. And other functions I did are correct.

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node * next;
}NODE, *PNODE;



 void sort_list(PNODE phead) {

    int len = length_list(phead);
    int temp, i, j;

    //method1
    PNODE p = phead->next;
    PNODE p1 = p->next;
    for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
            if ( p->data > p1->data) {
                temp = p->data;
                p->data = p1->data;
                p1->data = temp; 
            }
            p1 = p1->next;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }

    
    //method 2
    /*
    PNODE p;
    PNODE p1;
    for (i = 0, p = phead->next; i < len - 1; i++,p=p->next) {
        for (j = i + 1,p1=p->next; j < len; j++,p1=p1->next ) {
            if (p->data > p1->data) {
                temp = p->data;
                p->data = p1->data;
                p1->data = temp;
            }
        }
    }*/
```

Below is the create list and print function that you can run directly.

```
int main() {

PNODE phead = NULL;
phead = create_list(); 
sort_list(phead);
traverse_list(phead);
return 0;
}

PNODE create_list(void) {

int len;
int i = 0;
int val;
printf("input the list length: ");
scanf_s("%d", &len);
PNODE phead = (PNODE)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
PNODE ptail = phead;
ptail->next = NULL;

for (; i < len; i++) {      
    
    printf("input the data of the node: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &val);

    PNODE pNew = (PNODE) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    
    if (pNew == NULL) {
        printf("no memory");
        exit(-1);
    }
     
    pNew->data = val;
    pNew->next = NULL;  // create a new node

    ptail->next = pNew;  
    ptail = pNew;  // ptail record the previous node address.
    
}
return phead;
}

void traverse_list(PNODE phead) {

PNODE p = phead->next;

while (p != NULL) {

    printf("%d ", p->data);
    p = p->next;

}
return;
}

int length_list(PNODE phead) {

PNODE p = phead->next;

int len = 0;
while (p!= NULL) {
    len++;
    p = p->next;
}

return len;
}
```

Do I miss something in method 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `p1` before the second (and later) runs of inner loop in method 1.

```
//method1
PNODE p = phead->next;
// move this
// PNODE p1 = p->next;
for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    PNODE p1 = p->next; // here
    for (j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
        if ( p->data > p1->data) {
            temp = p->data;
            p->data = p1->data;
            p1->data = temp; 
        }
        p1 = p1->next;
    }
    p = p->next;
}
```